# Idle threads while new threads can be assigned to a nested loop

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

I have two nested loops:

```
!$omp parallel 
!$omp do
do i=1,4
  ...
  !$omp parallel 
  !$omp do
  do j=1,4
    call job(i,j)
```

My computer can run four threads in parallel. For the outer loop such four threads are created. The first three finish quickly since for `i=4`, the `job` is four times more expensive.

Now I expect that in the inner parallel region, new threads share the work. But this doesn't happen: The CPU load stays at 1/4, just as if the 4th thread works serially on the inner loop.

How can I allocate parallel CPU time to the inner parallel loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the following approach?

```
!$omp parallel do collapse(2)
do i = 1,4
do j = 1,4
    call job(i,j)
end do
end do
```

It should behave better.

Comment: My OpenMP introduction missed ``collapse``. However, I notice my situation is more complicated. Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020762/is-it-possible-to-cross-collapse-parallel-loops