# Is it possible to "cross collapse" parallel loops?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39019721/2525297), I actually have more complicated code with three loops:

```
!$omp parallel 
!$omp do
do i=1,4 ! can be parallelized
  ...
  do k=1,1000 !to be executed sequentially
    ...
    do j=1,4  ! can be parallelized
    call job(i,j)
```

The outer loops finish quickly except for `i=4`. So I want to start threads on the innermost loop, but leaving the `k`-loop sequentially within each `i`-iteration. In fact, `k` loops over the changing states of a random number generator, so this cannot be parallelized.

How can I collapse only the `i` and `j` loops? I suspect the `ordered` clause to be useful here, but I'm afraid that it would affect the inner loop again and still I'm unsure of the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine how that could work. Anyway, the `collapse` syntax definitely does not support that.

If you have load balancing issue, think about reordering your loops, using dynamic scheduling, OpenMP tasks or nested parallelism. There is not enough code to tell which might be applicable here.

Comment: Maybe a future OpenMP version? Technically, it should be possible to create new threads in the innermost loop while the outer idle threads free the CPU capacity.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, using nested parallelism.

Comment: Or just parallelize the inner loop. I am just concerned that it may not be efficient enough either if just the `j` loop from 1 to 4 is parallelizable and if it is run too often. (But that is true about nested parallelism as well if not more.)

Comment: I thought that generally parallelising the outer loops works better than parallelising inner loops? But is this is some Monti Carlo surrounding the inner loop, then doing the inner loop parallel makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If `1,4` is the real values you use in the outer loop, then I suggest to parallelize inner loops only (which can be parallelized), since there will be not much overhead.

Another suggestion is to swap `k` and `i` loops, if it's possible, so the outer loop would be loop in `k` and the two new inner loops in `i` and `j` could be parallelized together using collapse.

Answer (score 1):

A lightweight and uniform approach for this case is to use OpenMP tasks.
You can use them for both parallel loops or just for the inner one. In the second case, we will have a combination of the `for` and  `task` constructs. This solution exploits nested parallelism but avoids the implications of nested parallel regions. The `taskloop` construct is an equivalent and more automated approach.